# The teacher gets through this chapter too fast

Tags: idiomatic-language

> The teacher gets through this chapter too fast

I want to say that the teacher has not covered the chapter in details, and get through it too fast. Is it idiomatic to for the sentence above?

Answer (score 2):

If you're talking about something that the teacher already did, you need the **past tense**:

> The teacher **went** through **that** chapter too fast.

This sounds perfectly idiomatic.

Other ways of saying the same thing might be:

- The teacher did not cover that chapter in enough detail.
- The teacher sped through that chapter.
- The teacher did not explain that chapter thoroughly enough.